# Testing for Characters over a String

Tags: smalltalk, pharo

aSimple question i got, what's the easiest way to check if my String includes any alphabetic characters?? rather than streaming over it. I tried "isAlphaNumeric" gives me an error.

```
 |a|
 a:= '1625.46brd'.
 "check if a includes alphabets "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
a anySatisfy: [ :char | char isLetter ]
```

Here you iterate `a` as a *Collection* and check if any character is a letter. If you want it not only letters (I understand alphabet as letters) you can send `isAlphaNumeric` message.

Comment: In such cases, I tend to use symbols instead of blocks:

    a anySatisfy: #isLetter